# Dashboard Chart, what does 100 mean?

Tags: admin, dashboard

[image]What does the number **100 on the Y axis of the Dashboard** Chart mean?

Does anyone know? (the 100)

Comment: add dashboard screen shot here

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, see the issue on Magento repo: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7927

> Y-axis on dashboard graph always shows range 0 to 100 in steps of 10. That means quantity and amounts do not match actual value in graph.
>   Preconditions
>
> Any working setup for Magento 2
>   Tested on 2.1.1, but it probably doesn't work in any other
>
> Steps to reproduce
>
> Make few orders and look at the graph in admin dashboard
>
> Expected result
>
> Values shown should be matched with y-axis value
>
> Actual result
>
> It always show range 10 to 100 in steps of 10 and values (qty and amounts) doesn't make sense with that values
>
> Fortunately, that issue is easy to fix:
>   This code (exists in M1, not in M2) needs to be inserted on line 424 in vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php (thanks to @ivanweiler)

```
            } else if ($idx == 'y') {
                $valueBuffer[] = $indexid . ":|" . implode('|', $yLabels);
```

Answer (score 1):

It was issue with Y axis components in earlier version. This issue has been solved in Magento v2.2.x version.

I have taken following screen shot in Magento v2.2.4

[image]

[image]